# How do I make my web page able to be embedded with just the URL?

Tags: javascript, html

Many WYSIWYG web page editors such as Google Sites and Microsoft Team Sites use an embed widget that accepts a URL instead of an embed code like with YouTube. I'm trying to find resources on how this is done, but all of my searches keep coming up with how to embed something on your page. I don't want to embed something on my page, I want to create a page which can be embedded via the URL to that page.

Comment: So the url runs some JavaScript that outputs the content...

Comment: Do you mean write something that will generate static html markup from data that is retrieved from a URL? If so I am doing things like that by writing tags, and helpers for this static website generator I am using called hexo.io. Doing so is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Any site, unless it takes steps to prevent it, can be embedded using an iframe.

Sites which use specific embed code do so for a variety of reasons including:

- To include extra tracking code
- To display content in a specific sized frame
- To display a limited subset of content (e.g. just the video, to use YouTube as an example).

So given that: You want to be like YouTube and have your custom embed code be generated by sites based on just the URL to the main page.

Unfortunately your understanding of what is being done with that URL is backwards.

YouTube don't do anything special for Google Sites and Microsoft Team Sites to embed their content with "just a URL". All YouTube do is be popular. *The site doing the embedding* has made the effort to learn how to generate YouTube's embed code based on the URL and have written code to do that.